# Unable to get path even though it is correct

Tags: java, file, path

I'm trying to get my file path, to make sure it's the same I even used a function to return the path to the file, even though the path to the file is correct, it never works, I've tried to remove the .txt, to just have the file name (since it's on the same package as this class) but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code:

```
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try 
{
    String filetest="text.txt";
    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(filetest);
    String name = pathToFile.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    System.out.println("Path name: " + name);

    Stream<String> stream = Files.lines( Paths.get(name), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n"));
    String filename = contentBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(filename);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Output

```
Path name: C:\Users\Dias\eclipse-workspace\pds\text.txt
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Dias\eclipse-workspace\pds\text.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
    at java.nio.file.Files.lines(Files.java:3744)
    at lab7.Client.main(Client.java:23)
Error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Dias\eclipse-workspace\pds\text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the expected path

```
  C:\Users\Dias\eclipse-workspace\pds\text.txt
```

then the explanation is surely that the file does not exist.

If that is not the expected path then the explanation is that you need to either:

1. Code the path correctly in to your program, or
2. Change your current working directory

'toAbsolutePath' does not look around and find the file so it knows the absolute path; rather it sees that your specified path is relative, and prefixes it with the current workig directory.